# Regex - Output character not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to create a function to check if a field is valid **based on a set of characters** and, if not, **output which ones are not allowed**. Don't know if it is the best approach, but basically instead of telling the user which ones he can use, I want to tell which ones he can't.

```
function allowedString(field){
    var validCharacters = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ_-¿?¡!.,;:$() ]*$');
    if(!validCharacters.test(field.val())){
        var invalid = ?;
        return "Invalid characters: "+invalid;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have ; following the parenthesis not sure if that should be there

Comment: You could iterate through the String, and get each character which fails the regexp

Comment: The ; is allowed, that why I included it. About iterating the string, would that actually be a good approach? (thinking about performance on long strings)

Comment: You might be able to do a string.replace, and replace your regexp with '', then if the String is not empty, print the string, otherwise if it's empty the regexp passed

Comment: This function is passed once the required function was true. So some string is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your character set in your regex, you can remove all those characters from the string and resultant will be the non-allowed characters. Try this JS codes,

```js
function allowedString(s){
    var validCharacters = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ_-¿?¡!.,;:$() ]*$');
    if(!validCharacters.test(s)){
        var invalid = s.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ_-¿?¡!.,;:$() ]*/g,'');
        return "Invalid characters: "+invalid;
    } else {
        return "All characters are valid"; // return any message you want
    }

}


console.log(allowedString('aa@@bb##'));
console.log(allowedString('abc'));
console.log(allowedString('aa@@bb##~~^^'));
```

And change your `field` parameter in function back to your original code.

Comment: For some reason returns ".replace is not a function" when it shouldn't

Comment: @RGC: You need to use replace on string where as you might be using on `field`. Can you try doing `field.val().replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ_-¿?¡!.,;:$() ]*/g,'');`

Comment: You are right, I missed `.val()` Then, wouldn't it be the same to do `if(invalid !== "")`? Works when wrong, but when string is right return `Invalid character: `
I tried this, and it's ok for some like "#" but with "{" return ok..

Comment: Sure, I initially added the else part but since it wasn't in your function, I removed. I've updated the code to add show proper message in case all characters are valid. Please check.

Comment: Yes, it did!. I added return `Invalid characters: "+invalid.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");` so returns invalid characters only once.
I had to correct my expression to `[-a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ_¿?¡!.,;:$() ]`

Comment: Why do you want to do this `invalid.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");`? This will only replace the first occurrence of a character which occurs at least twice.

Comment: Because I use it to tell the user which characters cannot use. By adding that, if the user types "#" or "####" I just tell him he cannot use the character "#".

Comment: @RGC: Ok got it, and that's a good regex to remove all the duplicate characters from the string. Good job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and deal with it as with an array (not sure about the performance, though).

```
function allowedString(field){
    const validCharacters = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ_-¿?¡!.,;:$() ]*$');
    const disallowed = field.val().split('').filter(x => !validCharacters.test(x));

    if (disallowed.length) {
        return disallowed.join('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd reverse the test: Is there an invalid character within the string?

Take care you have to escape the dash in a character class except in first and last position.

```js
function allowedString(field){
    var invalidCharacters =/([^a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ_\-¿?¡!.,;:$() ])/;
    invalid = invalidCharacters.exec(field);
    if (invalid != null) {
        return "Invalid characters: "+invalid[1];
    } else {
        return "OK";
    }
}
console.log(allowedString('abc'));
console.log(allowedString('abc@def'));
console.log(allowedString('abc§def'));
```